# Looping num array para escolher sempre o próximo valor

Tags: php, mysql, array, loop

Tenho um array de usuários e preciso fazer um looping entre eles.
Irá funcionar assim, toda vez que alguem faz uma requisição na pagina, preciso que seja gravado no banco de dados o próximo usuário do que foi escolhido anteriormente.

Essa é minha array, que pego dos usuários cadastrados, essa array pode mudar.

```
array(
    (int) 1 => 'Joao',
    (int) 6 => 'Pedro',
    (int) 7 => 'Luiz',
    (int) 9 => 'Vinicius'
)
```

Ou seja, se na requisição anterior quem foi escolhido foi o `Pedro` (pego o id que foi salvo anteriormente) , preciso que na próxima ele salve o `id` do luiz no BD, e assim por diante...

Minha duvida está em, como "andar" com os valores dessa array tendo como base o ultimo valor registrado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após selecionar um usuário aleatoriamente do seu banco de dados, você poderia utilizar esta query para selecionar o "próximo" id após o atual:

```
SELECT * FROM sua_tabela WHERE id_usuario > $id_atual ORDER BY id_usuario ASC LIMIT 1
```

O que a query faz, basicamente, é trazer o próximo usuário com `id` maior que o atual, limitando a consulta a um resultado, ou seja, só traz o próximo.

No caso de o `id` já ser o último da lista, uma forma de "reiniciar" o loop seria utilizar um `if` no PHP para reiniciar o `$id_atual` para o menor possível.

Answer (score 0):

Cara da uma olhada na documentação do PHP, talvez nem precise ir no banco

Veja essas funções:

current() - Retorna o elemento corrente em um array
end() - Faz o ponteiro interno de um array apontar para o seu último elemento
next() - Avança o ponteiro interno de um array
reset() - Faz o ponteiro interno de um array apontar para o seu primeiro    elemento
each() - Retorna o par chave/valor corrente de um array e avança o seu cursor

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.next.php